# Decrypt chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

does anyone know how to get clear source code of this [extension](http://pastebin.com/y2crpBEF)?

Maybe via some extension to deobfuscate?

Answer (score 0):

Ask the author.

That's the only way you get the original source: obfuscation is not, in general, perfectly reversible.

De-obfuscation, even with tools, will require a lot of manual effort.